# Is there a way to create nested ordered list with combination of types - HTML + CSS + WordPress?

Tags: css, wordpress, nested, html-lists

I'm writing texts in WordPress that contains various combinations of nested ordered lists types.
I can't make any changes in texts because they are originals from the authors.

Is there a way to create this OL with CSS? 
Does counters work with numbers only?

Here are some examples of OL types combinations which I need to write in WP:

**First example:**

```
A. First
    A.1. First First
    A.2. First Second
B. Second
    B.1. Second First
        B.1.A. Second First First
C. Third
    ...
```

**Second example:**

```
1. First
    1.a. First First
        1.a.1. First First First
        1.a.1. First First Second
    1.b. First Second
2. Second
    ...
```

Comment: Just to get you started... there is a type attribute on ordered lists that allows you to change the numbering/lettering. It doesn't get you exactly what you're showing - but maybe close enough. For example, `<ol type="a">` will give you lowercase letters.

Comment: That examples are colored by system, I did not add any color to it. It should be only expamle of nested ordered list with some different types inside it.